# WPF/CaliburnMicro Bind one property to two form controls

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I have one `PersonModel` object, which has two properties, `FirstName` and `LastName`. I created a `CurrentPerson` property of type `PersonModel` in my ViewModel. When binding to the controls, whichever is bound to `x:Name` is the only one that shows up at runtime

**TextBlock Displays FirstName**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="CurrentPerson_FirstName" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CurrentPerson_FirstName}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

**TextBox Displays FirstName**

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CurrentPerson_FirstName}" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0" ></TextBlock>
 <TextBox Name="CurrentPerson_FirstName" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
```

How can I have both the TextBlock and the TextBox display the same data, and if the TextBox is typed in, the TextBlock and CurrentPerson will be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When not using `x:Name`, you should stick to the conventional naming pattern of using ".". In your TextBlock,  you need to replace "CurrentPerson_FirstName" with "CurrentPerson.FirstName".

For example,

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CurrentPerson.FirstName}" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0" ></TextBlock>
```

This should help you bind both control to same property.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know of a list of these types of conventions? It seems like I never know of something like this until I run into issues with it

Comment: @ZachRaudebaugh Happy to help you. Most of the conventions used by Caliburn micro are discussed here https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/conventions